# Data entry User form Application - winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

**Background**: I'm designing a system Data entry form using c# as front end and sql server 2008 as backend database. 
In this app I'm basically, just reading/writing to the database

**My issue:**

1. I never truly understood OOP, however I am getting more involved
   with it now, and while my program works, I want the code to be
   better (look better, be more flexible, utilize classes/objects more,
   etc.).
2. Being my first application I have no idea how messy the
   code is, if it conforms to guidelines, etc. Hopefully I will get
   some good feedback about improvements that can be made, but other
   than that, it works perfectly in all my tests!
3. I have written all the functionality in a single class with my understanding 
   it is not a correct way to do. But how to know whether which functionality 
   should be separated or aggregated

**Note: The code below is a fully working application where all the business case has been working fine.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//Wrote the code to populate the date time on the time of loding the form

            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

            try
            {
                DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(textBox1.Text);


//The user should not select the time that is greater than the current date time
                if (dt > dateTime )
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Dateshould not be greater than current date");
                    textBox1.Text = dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                }
                else if( dt <= dateTime.AddDays(-16))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Date Should Not Be Less Than 15days From The Current Date");
                    textBox1.Text = dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }



        private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /*The text should not be editable for the following textboes 
             1) Date
             2) username
             3) Total Audits Reviewed
             4) Audit carry forward
             5) Pending*/

            textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
            textBox9.ReadOnly = true;
            textBox12.ReadOnly = true;
            textBox8.ReadOnly = true;

            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.MinimizeBox = true;
            dateTimePicker1.Visible = false;
            textBox1.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            textBox11.Text = Environment.UserName;

            dropdown_combox1_values();
            dropdown_combox5_values();
            button2.Enabled = false;
            button3.Enabled = false;
            comboBox3.SelectedIndex = 4;
        }
        private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            dateTimePicker1.Visible = false;
        }


        private void textBox1_DoubleClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dateTimePicker1.Visible = true;
        }

        public void dropdown_combox1_values()
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Home Health - Post pay");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Home Health - Pre pay");
        }

        public void dropdown_combox5_values()
        {
            comboBox3.Items.Add("OASIS");
            comboBox3.Items.Add("Per visit");
            comboBox3.Items.Add("Leave");
            comboBox3.Items.Add("Holiday");

            comboBox3.Items.Add("N\\A");
            comboBox3.Items.Add("QC");

            comboBox3.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        }

        public void dropdown_combox2_values()
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Add("Humana OASIS");
            comboBox2.Items.Add("Humana Per visit");
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            comboBox2.Items.Clear();

            dropdown_combox2_values();

        }

        private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox2.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i;
            /*
             Check for test condition when the user will give data that violates the process
             */

            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex != -1)
                {

                    if (textBox2.Text != "")
                    {
                        if (int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out i))
                        {
                            if (textBox3.Text != "")
                            {
                                if (int.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out i))
                                {
                                    if (textBox4.Text != "")
                                    {
                                        if (int.TryParse(textBox4.Text, out i))
                                        {
                                            if (textBox5.Text != "")
                                            {
                                                if (int.TryParse(textBox5.Text, out i))
                                                {

                                                    if(textBox6.Text != "" )
                                                    {
                                                        if(int.TryParse(textBox6.Text, out i))
                                                        {
                                                            if(textBox7.Text != "")
                                                            {
                                                                if (int.TryParse(textBox7.Text, out i))
                                                                {
                                                                    if (textBox10.Text != "")
                                                                    {
                                                                        if(int.TryParse(textBox10.Text, out i))
                                                                        {
                                                                            if (comboBox3.SelectedIndex != -1)
                                                                            {
                                                                                calcuate_values();
                                                                            }
                                                                            else
                                                                            {
                                                                                MessageBox.Show("Please select the Appropriate Comment", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

                                                                            }



                                                                        }
                                                                        else
                                                                        {
                                                                            MessageBox.Show("Check whether the data is a number",
                                                    "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                                                                            textBox10.Text = "";
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                    else
                                                                    {

                                                                        MessageBox.Show("Provide Audits Assigned","Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                                                                    }


                                                                }
                                                                else
                                                                {
                                                                    MessageBox.Show("Check whether the data is a number",
                                                            "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                                                                    textBox7.Text = "";

                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                            else
                                                            {
                                                                MessageBox.Show("Provide Target/day",
                                                          "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                                                            }

                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            MessageBox.Show("Check whether the data is a number",
                                                            "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                                                            textBox6.Text = "";
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        MessageBox.Show("Provide Unfullfilled Data",
                                                            "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                                                    }

                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    MessageBox.Show("Check whether the data is a number", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                                                    textBox5.Text = "";

                                                }

                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                MessageBox.Show("Provide Rejection Data", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
MessageBoxIcon.Warning);


                                            }

                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            MessageBox.Show("Check whether the data is a number", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                                            textBox4.Text = "";
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        MessageBox.Show("Provide Total Findings Data", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                                         MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                                    }

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("Check whether the data is a number", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                           MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                                    textBox3.Text = "";

                                }

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Provide Partital Denial Data", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                                       MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Check whether the data is a number", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                                       MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                            textBox2.Text = "";
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Provide Full Denial Data", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                                       MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Select Workflow", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                                       MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Select Program", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                                       MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }

        }

        private void textBox11_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox11.ReadOnly = true;
        }

        private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        //private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //{


        //}


        public void calcuate_values()
        {

            try
            {

                var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"[NAS\kalais1].[HomeHealth_Validate_Search]", connection))
                    {
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        command.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = textBox1.Text;
                        command.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox11.Text;
                        command.Parameters.Add("@workflow", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox2.Text;
                        command.Parameters.Add("@program", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox1.Text;
                        SqlParameter returnParameter = command.Parameters.Add("RetVal", SqlDbType.Int);
                        returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        SqlDataReader oReader = command.ExecuteReader();

                            while (oReader.Read())
                            {
                                if (oReader["Pending_Audits"].ToString() == "Already exists")
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("The given workflow and program is already present for the given date");
                                    textBox12.Text = "";
                                    textBox8.Text = "";
                                    textBox9.Text = "";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    textBox12.Text =
                                                                                    (Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text) +
                                                                                     Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text) +
                                                                                     Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text)).ToString();
                                    textBox8.Text = oReader["Pending_Audits"].ToString();
                                    textBox9.Text =
                                        ((Convert.ToInt32(textBox10.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text)) -
                                         Convert.ToInt32(textBox12.Text)).ToString();
                                    MessageBox.Show("Validated the data! Please Submit.. ");

                                    button2.Enabled = true;
                                }
                    }
             }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Print error message
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void textBox10_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Show_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.ShowDialog();


        }
        public void ClearTextBoxes(Control control)
        {
            foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
            {
                if (c is TextBox)
                {
                    if (c.Name != "textBox11" && c.Name != "textBox1")
                    {
                        if (!(c.Parent is NumericUpDown))
                        {
                            ((TextBox) c).Clear();
                        }
                    }
                }
               else if (c is ComboBox)
                {
                    ((ComboBox)c).SelectedIndex = -1;
                    comboBox3.SelectedIndex = 4;
                }

                if (c.HasChildren)
                {
                    ClearTextBoxes(c);
                }
            }
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"[NAS\kalais1].[HomeHealth_Submit_test]", connection))
                {

                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = textBox1.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox11.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@workflow", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox2.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@program", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox1.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Full_Denial", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox2.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Partial_Denial", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox3.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@No_Findings", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox4.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Rejections", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox5.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Unfulfilled", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox6.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@TargetPerDay", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox7.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Audits_Assigned", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox10.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Total_Audits_Reviewed", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox12.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Audits_Carry_Forward", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox8.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Pending_Audits", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox9.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Comments", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox3.Text;

                    SqlParameter returnParameter = command.Parameters.Add("RetVal", SqlDbType.Int);
                    returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;


                    using (SqlDataReader oReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (oReader.Read())
                        {
                            if (oReader["comments1"].ToString() == "0")
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("CHECK THE COMMENTS AND THE GIVEN VALUE");

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Inserted");
                                ClearTextBoxes(this);
                                button2.Enabled = false;
                            }



                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        private void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = false;

            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex != -1)
                {
                    var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

                    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"[NAS\kalais1].[HomeHealth_Search]", connection))
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Workflow", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox2.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = textBox1.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox11.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@program", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox1.Text;
                    SqlParameter returnParameter = command.Parameters.Add("RetVal", SqlDbType.Int);
                    returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                   // command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    //MessageBox.Show(returnParameter.Value.ToString());

                    //MessageBox.Show(comboBox2.Text);

                    using (SqlDataReader oReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (oReader.Read())
                        {
                            if (oReader["Error"].ToString() == "0")
                            {

                                textBox2.Text = oReader["Full_Denial"].ToString();
                                textBox3.Text = oReader["Partial_Denial"].ToString();
                                textBox4.Text = oReader["No_Findings"].ToString();
                                textBox5.Text = oReader["Rejections"].ToString();
                                textBox6.Text = oReader["Unfulfilled"].ToString();
                                textBox7.Text = oReader["TargetPerDay"].ToString();
                                textBox10.Text = oReader["Audits_Assigned"].ToString();
                                comboBox3.Text = oReader["Comments"].ToString();
                                textBox12.Text = oReader["Total_Audits_Reviewed"].ToString();
                                textBox8.Text = oReader["Audits_Carry_Forward"].ToString();
                                textBox9.Text = oReader["Pending_Audits"].ToString();
                                MessageBox.Show("Required Data... Has been populated");
                                button3.Enabled = true;
                                comboBox1.Enabled = false;
                                comboBox2.Enabled = false;

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Check Whether You have selected Program and workflow currectly");
                                ClearTextBoxes(this);
                                comboBox1.Enabled = true;

                                comboBox2.Enabled = true;
                                button1.Enabled = true;

                            }


                        }

                    }
                }

            }

                }
                else
                {
                MessageBox.Show("Select Workflow", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                                       MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Select Program", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                                       MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }


        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox12.Text =
                                                                                   (Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text) +
                                                                                    Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text) +
                                                                                    Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text)).ToString();

            textBox9.Text =
                                       ((Convert.ToInt32(textBox10.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text)) -
                                        Convert.ToInt32(textBox12.Text)).ToString();



            var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"[NAS\kalais1].[HomeHealth_Update]", connection))
                {

                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Workflow", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox2.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = textBox1.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox11.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Program", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox1.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Full_Denial", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox2.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Partial_Denial", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox3.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@No_Findings", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox4.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Rejections", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox5.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Unfulfilled", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox6.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@TargetPerDay", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox7.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Audits_Assigned", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox10.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Total_Audits_Reviewed", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox12.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Audits_Carry_Forward", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox8.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Pending_Audits", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox9.Text;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Comments", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox3.Text;

                    SqlParameter returnParameter = command.Parameters.Add("RetVal", SqlDbType.Int);
                    returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;


                    using (SqlDataReader oReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (oReader.Read())
                        {
                            if (oReader["comments1"].ToString() == "0")
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Please.. Check the comments and populated values");

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Updated");
                                ClearTextBoxes(this);
                                comboBox1.Enabled = true;

                                comboBox2.Enabled = true;
                                button1.Enabled = true;
                                button2.Enabled = false;
                                button3.Enabled = false;

                            }



                        }
                    }

                     }
            }


            }



    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe what your application is doing in more detail. It'd be great if you could also share a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Some quick remarks

- Name you things properly. E.g `comboBox3` will make you wonder what it is, if you come in 2 months to fix a bug or add some functionality. Always name your things in a way that you see at first glance what they are about.
- Instead of using `DateTime.Parse()` inside a `try..catch` where you swallow every exception you either should use `DateTime.TryParse()` or catch the `FormatException` which the method would throw. But not only catching you should but for a gui you should also inform the user that something went wrong.
- Inside the `button1_Click()` method you could avoid the [Arrow Anti Pattern](http://wiki.c2.com/?ArrowAntiPattern) which makes your code almost unreadable, by returning early like e.g

  ```
  if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
  {
      MessageBox.Show("Select Program", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
      return;
  }
  if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex != -1)
  {
      MessageBox.Show("Select Workflow", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
      return ;
  }  

  ....
  ```
- commented out code is dead code which should be removed like e.g

  ```
  //private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  //{


  //}
  ```
- In `calcuate_values()` you have used some `using`'s which is the way to go but unfortunately you have forgotten to enclose the using of `SqlDataReader` in a `using` as well.
- While we are at `calcuate_values()` I would like to mention that it is a good habit to stick to the [.NET Naming Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) because other developers will do as well and it becomes easier for them to read your code.
- The name of `ClearTextBoxes()` is misleading because it "resets" comboboxes as well.
- The formatting of your code (the indentation of the lines)  looks strange but maybe this is due to copy pasting it here.
- Blank lines are a good way to group related stuff but to many of them are reducing the readability.

Comment: zombie down (+1)